Is the reason a womans testimony is half because women weren't involved with money
Is it true that a reason a womans testimony is half in money is because women weren't involved in money related things?

What do you know about the Prophets first wife? Look it up and it will answer at least a part of your question. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khadija_bint_Khuwaylid )

I am not completely sure if you don't mix up the english words testimony and inheritance. Your question would make sense with both, but the later has more to do with money. Having much money doesn't make anyone more trustworthy.

A woman's testimony is not half. I don't know from where you get it.
If you are referring to the same old repeated quranic verse 2:282, then it doesn't mean that a woman's testimony is half. It's just a guideline for a specific time period (where most people were illiterate especially women) and in the case of counting/financial analysis only.
It is not saying (2) both women should testify, the role of the second woman is clearly stated as an assistant IF needed, If the 2nd witness sees something amiss by the first woman, she advises the first woman on something amiss, a 2nd set of eyes on a matter they are less a part of in most cases, it is entirely up to the first woman to accept the 2nd woman's suggestion because that first woman's testimony remains her own, no one else's and not 2 women. The verse proves the 2nd woman is not someone who gives testimony but someone who serves as a reminder to the first woman in these cases.
Since in 21st century women and men are attending the same schools and universities so whatever this verse implies is completely obsolete in present context.
So, please get rid if these sexist ideas and questions and do not spread them further as it is common sense nowadays to treat everyone equal and not demean them because of their gender.
